# How can I change the format of DateTime?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, datetime

I'm trying to make a string format that, when a user post is uploaded, it expresses the upload time as "~ minutes ago" or "~ hours ago" and so on.

My application works in the way like below

upload post in **PostActivity** > **firebase** saves the data of the post (the post is consist of postId, writerId, message, writeTime, bgUri for image, commentCount) > **MainActivity** gets data from firebase and shows the post on **RecycleView** by **MyAdapter.kt**

Below is the `PostActivity.kt`

```
class PostActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_post)

      supportActionBar?.title = "New Post"
      val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@PostActivity)
      layoutManager.orientation = LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL

    
      recyclerView2.layoutManager=layoutManager
      recyclerView2.adapter = MyAdapter()

      postButton.setOnClickListener {

         val newRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts").push()
         
         post.writeTime= DateTime().toString()

         newRef.setValue(post)
         finish()
     }
 }
```

The `writeTime` field of `post` is DateTime().toString().

For the string format, I made a function `getdiffTimeText()` at `MyAdapter.kt` which is below.

```
class MyAdapter(private val posts : MutableList<Post>) :  RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>() { //line 20
   
   override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyAdapter.MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
       val post = posts[position]

       holder.timeTextView.text = getDiffTimeText(post.writeTime) //line 32 
   }

   public class MyViewHolder(itemView : View) : 
       val timeTextView = itemView?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.timeTextView) //line 51           
   }
}
fun getDiffTimeText(targetTime: String): String {

   val curDateTime = DateTime()
   val targetDateTime = DateTime(targetTime)

   val diffDay = Days.daysBetween(curDateTime, targetDateTime).days
   val diffHours = Hours.hoursBetween(targetDateTime, curDateTime).hours
   val diffMinutes = Minutes.minutesBetween(targetDateTime, curDateTime).minutes
   if (diffDay == 0) {
       if (diffDay == 0 && diffMinutes == 0) {
           return "just before"
       }
       return if (diffHours > 0) {
           "" + diffHours + "hours ago"
       } else "" + diffMinutes + "minutes ago"

   } else {
       val format = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd")
       return format.format(Date(targetTime))
   }
}
```

Below is the MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

   val posts: MutableList<Post> = mutableListOf()

   private lateinit var dbref: DatabaseReference

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

      getUserData()
   }

   private fun getUserData() {
      dbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/Posts")
      dbref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
         override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                for (userSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                    val post = userSnapshot.getValue(Post::class.java)
                    posts.add(post!!)
                }
                recyclerView_main.adapter = MyAdapter(posts)
             }
         }

         override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
         }
     })
  }
}
```

Below is Post.kt the class of user's post.

```
class Post {
var postId = ""
var writerId = ""
var message = ""

var writeTime = ""

var bgUri = ""
var commentCount = ""
}
```

When I run the code, app crashes with the error below.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "1661861458" is malformed at "8"
   
    at org.joda.time.DateTime.<init>(DateTime.java:257)
    at <<package name>>.MyAdapterKt.getDiffTimeText(MyAdapter.kt:51)
    at <<package name>>.MyAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.kt:32)
    at <<package name>>.MyAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.kt:20)
```

To test the fuction `getDiffTimeText()` I tried the code below in different activity.

```
val testTime = DateTime().toString()

val testText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.testing)
val testText2 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.testing2)

testText.text = testTime
testText2.text = getDiffTimeText(testTime)
```

The `testTime` is String type just like the Post.kt where the type of writeTime field is String.

As the result, textview `testText` shows `2022-08-31T05:37:55.778Z` which is the current time, and `testText2` shows `just ago`.
So it seems the function `getDiffTimeText` works in this way. But It doesn't work in `holder.timeTextView.text = getDiffTimeText(post.writeTime)` which is `MyAdapter.kt` line 32, and the app crashes.
How should I solve this?

*edited my question for clearence, codes that are less relevant are excluded.

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal block of code that exemplifies your question? This makes it a lot easier to answer your question.

Comment: It's not recommended to use JodaTime anymore… There's `java.time`, which is also the base of `kotlinx.datetime`. Better use one of those, you can easily extend a `java.time.Duration` with a suitable (e.g.) `fun Duration.timeAgo()` that prints what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Seem the timestamp you passed in line 32 `holder.timeTextView.text = getDiffTimeText(post.writeTime)` is counting with second instead of millis.

You can try to changed your remote time to millis or just do like that:

```kotlin
val timeInMillis = post.writeTime.toLong() * 1000L // maybe toLongOrNull() for safe usage.
holder.timeTextView.text = getDiffTimeText(timeInMillis.toString())
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this approach to fix my issue: Though in my case I was just calculating the time and not date. But you can have some idea.

So I was trying to store the time in milliseconds and then retrieving it back to show in a desired format:

Here are the steps I followed:

**First saving the time in database**

1. Getting the time from Time Picker :

```
val h = picker.hour
val m = picker.minute
```

2. Converting the total time to milliseconds

```
val hour = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(h.toLong())
val minute = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(m.toLong())
val totalTime = hour + minute
```

3. Saving the time as a string. (in my case it was Room DB, you can do on Firebase)

**Now retrieving the time from database**

1. Initially converted the entered time back to Long from String

```
  val timeMilliseconds = totalTime.toLong()
```

2. Converting the milliseconds to hours, minutes and seconds with help of function

```
 val startTime = formatToDigitalClock(timeMilliseconds)
```

3. The function

```
//Converting received long time to proper digital format
    private fun formatToDigitalClock(milliseconds: Long): String {
        val hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(milliseconds).toInt() % 24
        val minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milliseconds).toInt() % 60
        val seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(milliseconds).toInt() % 60

        return when {
            hours > 0 -> String.format("%d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds)
            minutes > 0 -> String.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds)
            seconds > 0 -> String.format("00:%02d", seconds)

            else -> {
                "00:00"
            }
        }
    }
```

You can further change the String format in a way so that you can show your time like ("2 hours ago")

Answer (score 0):

If `post.writeTime.toLong()` causes a `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2022-08-31T04:20:45.265Z"`, I'll have to conclude that the type of `post.writeTime` is `String` in ISO standard.

There's a simple way to parse those ISO standards in `java.time`, in this case you can do

```kotlin
OffsetDateTime.parse(post.writeTime)
```

and use that to calculate the difference / time elapsed until *now* (in code: `OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)`). You will need a `ZoneOffset` because the `String` returned by `post.writeTime` also has one (the `Z` at the end is UTC resp. an offset of +00:00 hours).

The elapsed time can be calculated by means of a `java.time.Duration`:

```kotlin
val duration = Duration.between(
                   OffsetDateTime.parse(post.writeTime),
                   OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)
               )
```

A `Duration` represents elapsed time in hours, minutes, seconds, millis and even nanos, I think. However, only hours, minutes and seconds should matter here (correct me if I'm wrong).

Now the Kotlin magic comes into play: We can write an extension function for `Duration`, one that simply checks the values top-down (hours first, if zero, use minutes, if zero, use seconds, if zero write some statement):

```kotlin
fun Duration.timeAgo(): String {
    return when {
        this.toHours() > 0 -> "${this.toHours()} hours ago"
        this.toMinutes() > 0 -> "${this.toMinutes()} minutes ago"
        this.toSeconds() > 0 -> "${this.toSeconds()} seconds ago"
        else -> "a moment ago"
    }
}
```

Example in a `main` using the time `String` from your comment below another answer and the code mentioned above (in this answer):

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val duration = Duration.between(
        OffsetDateTime.parse("2022-08-31T04:20:45.265Z"),
        OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)
    )

    println(duration.timeAgo())
}
```

Result (attention, it depends on the runtime of the code):

```
3 hours ago
```

Some examples with `Duration`s of differen values:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val durOne = Duration.ofHours(2).plusMinutes(13).plusSeconds(53)
    val durTwo = Duration.ofMinutes(13).plusSeconds(53)
    val durThree = Duration.ofSeconds(53).plusMillis(20)
    val durFour = Duration.ofMillis(20)

    println("${durOne.timeAgo()}")
    println("${durTwo.timeAgo()}")
    println("${durThree.timeAgo()}")
    println("${durFour.timeAgo()}")
}
```

Output:

```
2 hours ago
13 minutes ago
53 seconds ago
a moment ago
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I found out that there was a problem on my database.

Answer (score 0):

there were data on my database which I stored before, and I missed that those data  had different structure about writetime. So that caused  the crash on loading data. After removing those, it worked well.